# Win32: How to use RegisterTypeLib API from standard user

Tags: security, winapi

The Win32 API call [RegisterTypeLib()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms221570.aspx) is used to create the registry keys necessary to register a type library.

Unfortunatly, on Windows XP, it tries to write those registry key entries to

```
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\TypeLib
```

rather than

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\TypeLib
```

Meaning that a standard user will not be able to run an ActiveX.

In May 2008 Microsoft released a [hotfix for Vista](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/935200) to correct this issue - but the problem remains on Windows XP.

What's a standard-user friendly developer to do?

---

### Answer 1

Use the API call that is designed for it:

[RegisterTypeLibraryForUser()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms221504.aspx)

### Answer 2

If you can't fix it, hack it:

```
//begin hack
HKEY key;
RegOpenKeyW(HKEY_CURRENT_USER, @"Software\Classes", out key);
RegOverridePredefKey(HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT, key);

//do original work
RegisterTypeLibrary(...)

//stop hacking
RegOverridePredefKey(HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT, null);
RegCloseKey(key);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `RegOverridePredefKey()` API to map the `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT` regtree to `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes`:

- [`http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724901.aspx`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724901.aspx)

Comment: Starting with Windows Vista SP1 you should call "OaEnablePerUserTLibRegistration" to allow RegisterTypeLibrary for the user in your running application.
Only calling "RegisterTypeLibrary" isn't enough.

MSDN: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc713570(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 6):

Take a look at this blog entry I wrote.  It will registry ATL COM objects into HKCU instead of HKCR using RegOverridePredefKey.  You can use the same technique to call RegisterTypeLib and have it properly register under HKCU

[Register ATL as Normal User](http://blogs.msdn.com/jaredpar/archive/2005/05/29/423000.aspx)