# Register applications via Registry table rather than TLBs

Tags: delphi, windows-installer, registry, typelib

We register the capabilities of Delphi applications using TLB files. However, from reading [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa372092%28VS.85%29.aspx), "Installation package authors are strongly advised against using the TypeLib table. Instead, they should register type libraries by using the Registry table". Does anyone have any advice on how to do this in a 'Delphi' way for Windows 7?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to answer my own question! This is a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/285400/win32-how-to-use-registertypelib-api-from-standard-user), which seems to have the answer I needed (just in a different language that I would normally use).

Answer (score 1):

It means you would need to figure out what registry entries to add to register the tlb. [This](http://blogs.msdn.com/larryosterman/archive/2006/01/09/510856.aspx) explains what needs to be done. You could also use a tool like REGCAP.EXE which comes with Visual and generates a .reg file. If you use [WiX](http://wix.sf.net) to build your msi you could use tools like tallow and heat to let them generate the wix files for you.